# How to search Array for multiple values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, search, duplicates, key

I need to get the keys from values that are duplicates. I tried to use array_search and that worked fine, BUT I only got the first value as a hit.

I need to get both keys from the duplicate values, in this case 0 and 2. The search result output as an array would be good.

Is there a PHP function to do this or do I need to write some multiple loops to do it?

```
$list[0][0] = "2009-09-09";
$list[0][1] = "2009-05-05";
$list[0][2] = "2009-09-09";
$list[1][0] = "first-paid";
$list[1][1] = "1";
$list[1][2] = "last-unpaid";

echo array_search("2009-09-09",$list[0]);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want [array_keys](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the search value

```
array_keys($list[0], "2009-09-09");
```

which will return an array of the keys with the specified value, in your case [0, 2]. If you want to find the duplicates as well, you can first make a pass with [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), then iterate over that array using array_keys on the original; anything which returns an array of length > 1 is a duplicate, and the result is the keys in which the duplicates are stored. Something like...

```
$uniqueKeys = array_unique($list[0])

foreach ($uniqueKeys as $uniqueKey)
{
  $v = array_keys($list[0], $uniqueKey);

  if (count($v) > 1)
  {
    foreach ($v as $key)
    {
      // Work with $list[0][$key]
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I copy pasted the first line of code. It works like expected.

Comment: array_keys Will be more help up

Answer (score 12):

In [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) we can read:

> If needle  is found in haystack  more
>   than once, the first matching key is
>   returned. To return the keys for all
>   matching values, use [`array_keys()`](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with
>   the optional `search_value` parameter
>   instead.

Comment: an array is like this   (0 =>(student_id=>10215, roll_no => 23), 1 =>(......)) How do I  search the student_id of the key which has a roll no. 23.

Answer (score 8):

The following combination of function calls will give you all duplicate values:

```
$a = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99, 2, 5, 2);

$unique     = array_unique($a); // preserves keys
$diffkeys   = array_diff_key($a, $unique);
$duplicates = array_unique($diffkeys);

echo 'Duplicates: ' . join(' ', $duplicates) . "\n"; // 1 2 5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) by using `while` loop and the following workaround:

```
while (($key = array_search("2009-09-09", $list[0])) !== FALSE) {
  print($key);
  unset($list[0][$key]);
}
```

<sup>Source: [cue at openxbox at php.net](http://php.net/array_search)</sup>

For one-multidimensional array, you may use the following function to achieve that (as alternative to [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys)):

```
function array_isearch($str, $array){
  $found = array();
  foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (strtolower($v) == strtolower($str)) {
      $found[] = $k;
    }
  }
  return $found;
}
```

<sup>Source: [robertark, php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#77525)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The PHP manual states in the [`Return Value` section of the `array_search()` function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#function.array-search.returnvalues) that you can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to accomplish this. You just need to provide the second parameter:

```
$keys = array_keys($list[0], "2009-09-09");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userdb=Array
(
    (0) => Array
        (
            (uid) => '100',
            (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
            (url) => 'urlof100'
        ),
);

$key = array_search(100, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.