# PHP - If any array values match then remove all of them

Tags: php, arrays

I'm kind of stuck here on what I think must have quite a simple solution.

Say I have an array:

```
$A = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 13);
```

How could I possibly remove all of the values that occur more than once?

So I'm left with an array that looks like this

```
$A = array(2, 4, 6, 13);
```

I've tried using array unique, but that just removes duplicates leaving you with a single value. I need to use the following logic: if there are any values that match - then remove all of the values that match.

Comment: What have you been trying?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i'm going for, is there any built in PHP function that does this?

Comment: FYI:  I noticed my answer below had a typo.  It's now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try something like this.

```
$A = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 13);

$A = array_count_values($A);
foreach($A as $key => $value) {
    if($value > 1)
      unset($A[$key]);
}
$A = array_keys($A);
print_r($A);
```

edit:  fixed error

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 13
)
```

Comment: Simple is often better, and in this case, RichardW11's answer is twice as fast as the array_filter() version of Amal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a custom callback to filter out the array values which repeat more than once:

```
function removeDuplicates($array) {
    $values = array_count_values($array);
    return array_filter($array, function($item) use ($values) {
        return $values[$item] === 1;
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$A = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 13);
print_r( removeDuplicates($A) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 6
    [8] => 13
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/77695)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with abit of coding.

First see this SO post to get a list of all the duplicates using array_unique:

[php return only duplicated entries from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259407/php-return-only-duplicated-entries-from-an-array)

Then you'll have to loop through the duplicates returned from the link above and do an array_search to return the index of the values and then array_splice to actually remove it.

I don't know of any code that will do this in one step for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with PHP >= 5.3):

```
$A = array_keys(array_filter(
    array_count_values($A), 
    function ($count) 
    {
        return $count == 1;
    }
));
```

**Explanation:**

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function (in this case [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) . If the frequency is 1, the current value from array is returned into the result array.

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) returns the keys from the array, in this case the values with frequency equal to 1.

So, the compressed "one-line" form is:

```
$A=array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($A),function($c){return $c==1;}));
```