# getting duplicate entries from array (instead of just removing them)

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array with possible duplicate values, and I want not only to remove them (i use `array_unique` for that), but extract them in anothr array.

i.e.

```
$a = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6);
$b = array_unique($a); // has 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I want a third array ($c) with the duplicates only

that is, with [2,4,6] or [2,4,6,6] (either would do)

whats the easiest way of doing it?

I tried `$c = array_diff($a,$b)`, but gives an empty array, since it is removing all of the occurrences of $b from $a (because, of course, they occur at least once in $b)

I also thought of `array_intersect`, but it result in an array exactly like $a

Is there a direct function in php to achieve this? How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259407/php-return-only-duplicated-entries-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found such solution on Internet:

```
$c = array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $a, array_unique( $a ) ) );
```

But it doesn't seem easy to understand

Comment: In fact, little after posting my question, I found this same solution, it was included on a comment on the php array_unique docs, [here](http://mx2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#95203) . It works as expected (gives `[2,4,6]` in my example), although as you say, it's not that easy to understand how it works.

Comment: update, in fact, using just the inner part of the solution `$c = array_diff_assoc($a,array_unique($a))` , you get my other expected result `[2,4,6,6]`, yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_count_values` to count the # of occurrences of each element and use `array_filter` to only keep those that occur more than once.

```
$a = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6);
$b = array_count_values($a);
$c = array_filter($b,function($val){ return $val > 1; });
$c = array_keys($c);
print_r($c);
```

---

If your input array is sorted you can find dupes by looping through the array and checking if the previous element is equal to the current one

```
$a = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6);
$dupes = array();

foreach($a as $i => $v) {
    if($i > 0 && $a[--$i] === $v)
        $dupes[] = $v;
}

print_r($dupes);
```