# Check if multiple dates are the same in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have an "Events" table in MySQL : 
EventsDate('id','event','start_date','end_date')

I'd like to check if multiple events have the same start date to show it differently in my HTML template.
My SQL request is :
`SELECT * FROM EVENTSDATE where event='$id' and  start_date>='$today' order by start_date asc`

Now my foreach :

```
foreach ($upcomingDates as $value) { //$upcoming is the array with my sql request

        }
```

How can I say : "if you find two rows with the same start_date, echo something"

Comment: the way I would do it is add each date to an array as a key, then use array_key_exists (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp) to see if it is already in the array prior to adding it.

Comment: You have to run another sql-query to select duplicates with the same start date.

Comment: If you're searching by id, why would you have multiple rows in your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach.

```
// Array to contain all values
$container = array();

// Loop through your existing array
foreach ($upcomingDates as $key => $value) {
    // Check if the value is already in the container array
    // If this is the case, its a duplicate.
    if (array_key_exists($value['start_date'], $container)) {
        $container[$value['start_date']]++;
        echo $value.' is a duplicate with key '.$key;
    }

    // Add each value to the array
    $container[$value['start_date']] = 1;
}
```

Another method is to use `array_count_values()`

```
foreach(array_count_values($upcomingDates) as $value => $c) {
    if ($c > 1) {
        echo $value.' is a duplicate';
    }
}
```

Note that the second option won't work if your `$upcomingDates` is an array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your second method, I obtain this error : `Can only count STRING and INTEGER values`

Comment: Are your values `DateTime` objects?

Comment: They're stored in varchar

Comment: @TyYt I edited my answer to let the first part work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an empty array before the for loop, and add each value in as a key. Then, on each iteration you can check that array for the key, like so:

```
$values = [];
foreach ($upcomingDates as $value) { //$upcoming is the array with my sql request
    if(isset($values[$value])) //duplicate value found
        //do something here
    $values[$value] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're ordering your events by `start_date`:

```
for ($i = 0, $length = count($upcomingDates); $i < $length; $i++) {
    $date = $upcomingDates[$i];

    if (isset($upcomingDates[$i + 1]) &&
        $upcomingDates[$i + 1]['start_date'] == $date['state_date']) {
        echo 'this and the next date are equal';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me understand it and try :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out GROUP BY

look here: [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Futhermore: links will get deleted one day, then your posting wouldnt have any impact anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find duplicates, then you can directly get it from database 
ex. 
 
`SELECT * FROM EVENTSDATE where event='$id' and  start_date>='$today' GROUP BY start_date having count(start_date) > 1 order by start_date asc`

or you can find duplicates from resulting array
[return only duplicated entries from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259407/php-return-only-duplicated-entries-from-an-array)

Comment: Yes, already done in my SQL request but I would like to try in PHP. A little challenge ^^ Thanks !