# Search in multidimensional array by several values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I'm sure there are some duplicate values in it, I want to search in this array and find the duplicate values and return the key of that array.

let me explain with an example, this is my array:

```
[
  0 => [
      'name' => 'name0',
      'family' => 'family0',
      'email' => 'email0@sample.com',
      'rate' => 10
  ],
  1 => [
      'name' => 'name1',
      'family' => 'family1',
      'email' => 'email1@sample.com',
      'rate' => 4
  ],
  2 => [
      'name' => 'name0',
      'family' => 'family0',
      'email' => 'email0@sample.com',
      'rate' => 6
  ]
];
```

Now, I want to search in this array by `name`, `family`, and `email` at the same time and return the key of the parent (in this example 0 and 2). because I want to create a new array like this :

```
[
  0 => [
      'name' => 'name0',
      'family' => 'family0',
      'email' => 'email0@sample.com',
      'rate' => [
          10,
          6
      ]
  ],
  1 => [
      'name' => 'name1',
      'family' => 'family1',
      'email' => 'email1@sample.com',
      'rate' => [
          4
      ]
  ],
];
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: array_unique maybe u want do it

Comment: Do you want to find all the duplicates and return the keys, or do you want to just build the new array?

Comment: @BrettGregson Yes, exactly, I can use another loop to create a new array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259407/php-return-only-duplicated-entries-from-an-array similar exam

Comment: @dılosürücü As I understand in the `array_unique` all values should be the same, but in my sample some values (`rate`) is different and just some values are same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array-reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and use the 3 similar fields as keys.

Define a function who create the key and set or add rate:

```
function combineRate($carry, $item) {
    $k = implode('###', array($item['name'], $item['family'], $item['email']));
    if (isset($carry[$k]))
        $carry[$k]['rate'][] = $item['rate'];
    else {
        $item['rate'] = [$item['rate']];
        $carry[$k] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}
```

Call it with empty array:

```
$res = array_values(array_reduce($a, 'combineRate', array()));
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/OFVpD)