# Search array and return multiple matches

Tags: php

For example if I am searching for a key with a value `5` in my array `$cake`, I could use the following code:

```
$cake = array("a"=>6,"b"=>5,"c"=>6);
echo array_search(5, $cake, true); // returns "b";
```

But if my `$cake` array contains *multiple matches*, only the first match is returned:

```
$cake = array("a"=>6,"b"=>5,"c"=>5,"d"=>5,"e"=>5);
echo array_search(5, $cake, true); // returns "b";
```

**How can I return multiple matches as an array? Like this:**

```
$cake = array("a"=>6,"b"=>5,"c"=>5,"d"=>5,"e"=>5);
// return array("b","c","d","e");
```

Comment: Can't you just loop though the array?

Comment: ^yes but doesnt php have any built-in functions to do this?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212605/php-array-search-for-multiple-values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

```
print_r(array_keys($cake, 5, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
for($index = 0; $index <= count($cake); $index++){
    if(!array_search(5, $cake[$index], true) == false){
        echo array_search(5, $cake[$index], true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

> **array_intersect** — Computes the intersection of arrays

```
 $matches = array_keys(array_intersect($cake, array(5)));
 print_r($matches);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
    [2] => d
    [3] => e
)
```