# PHP Get multiple highest values from array

Tags: php, arrays, key, max

I have a script that puts a bunch of variables (in this case random letters A through D) into an array, counts the frequency of these variables, finds the highest frequency and then finds the key that matches this frequency.

```
$answerlist = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4,);
$count = array_count_values($answerlist);
$high_value = max($count);
$high_key = array_search($high_value, $count); 
print_r ($high_key);
```

However in a case where there are 2 equal highest values, array_search only returns the first key. Is there a way to return both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Array search for multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212605/php-array-search-for-multiple-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$high_keys = array_keys($count, $high_value);
```

From the [`array_search` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues):

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.