# How to retrieve all maximum values from array?

Tags: php, arrays, max, aggregate-functions

I need to get all maximum values from array using php.

For this array:

```
$arr = array('a'=>10,'b'=>20,'c'=>5,'d'=>20);
```

I used below code,

```
$key = array_search(max($arr), $arr);
```

but I get only `b`, I need to get both `b` and `d` -- all keys with the highest value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return index of highest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Get multiple highest values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484765/php-get-multiple-highest-values-from-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find **all** keys use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) with a second parameter:

```
$arr = array('a'=>10,'b'=>20,'c'=>5,'d'=>20);
$key = array_keys($arr, max($arr));
```

By the way it is said on [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues) man page)